# Running code remotely from local text editor

Tags: atom-editor, remote-debugging, text-editor, sshfs

Currently on my local machine I mount a copy of my remote folders using sshfs and oxfuse. This allows me to edit my remote scripts in a local copy of atom.

However for running sections of code I currently copy the code, and paste it into an ipython window on the remote desktop (accessed via nomachine).

This is rather inefficient way of developing/debugging. Is there anyway to e.g. run the code in atom through the remote kernel? I am happy to e.g. change text editors if this would make it possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely run code remotely. The easiest way is to install a terminal package (I use [`termination`](https://atom.io/packages/termination)) and from that use SSH to get into the remote server. If you feel like being fancy, you could use [`process-palette`](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette) to issue specific commands over SSH connections that exist solely to run that one script and then terminate. Since the file name is the same in Atom as on the remote server, you can use variables to fully automate it.